# D3 chord diagram with exact positions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, circos, chord-diagram

I want to create [chord diagram in D3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/chord.html), but to specify relations of intervals with exact positions as in the following example by [Circos](http://circos.ca): [image: Sibelia comparative genomics example].

Is there a way to do it in D3?

If not, is there a way to do it in any other javscript data visualization library?